# "Story", "short story", "tale", "fairy tale" in Russian

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, значения

What are the various ways to express **story**, **short story**, **tale**, and **fairy tale** in Russian?

Another way to put the question: what are the differences between **история**, **сказка**, **рассказ**, **повесть**, and other related words, in terms of everyday usage?

The only obvious difference to me is **история** means **history**, otherwise I see **story**, **short story**, and/or **tale** listed for basically all of them in the dictionary, which is not useful for knowing when to correctly use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**история** is a series of events happened. Usually it's about real events, if it's a fantasy story, the story teller is supposed to indicate it. For example:  "Вот такая история у нас случилась: родился телёнок о двух головах".

***история*** as history is a different meaning of the same word. It's series of events from the past, described by a historian.

**сказка** is a fairy tale.

**рассказ** is

1) the result of someone telling *история*. For example:
- Вот такая история у нас случилась. [...]
Он закончил рассказ и ушёл.

2) A short story, usually published.

**повесть** in a past could be used for any quite long *рассказ*, but nowadays it's only a form of literature, similar to novel, which is much larger than a  short story, but shorter than a general novel (*роман*). Philologist define difference between *повесть* and *роман* in main character(s) personality change. No changing at all is for a *повесть*, otherwise it's *роман*. In collocation, there is only size difference. For example, 200 book pages is *повесть*, 500 is *роман*.

Comment: Отличие повести от романа все-таки не в размере, а в количестве сюжетных линий. У повести всегда одна сюжетная линия, у романа - минимум две.

Answer (score 0):

Сказка is a fairytale, usually with fantastic. If somebody told a story (which is called "история" by him) which happened with him, others don't believe him because that story doesn't look real, they could say that it is a "сказка"

рассказ and повесть are used for literature. In short, рассказ is smaller.